# How to concatenate char "symbol" to String in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to display the following text:  **index/size** for example; 1/5, I wrote the following tag:

```
    <c:out value="${blocCourant.titre} ${fn:length(blocCourant.questions)>1 ? questionCourante.indice '/'
                                 fn:length(blocCourant.questions) : ''}" escapeXml="false" />
```

I tried also without as follow but it didn't work':

```
    <c:out value="${blocCourant.titre} ${fn:length(blocCourant.questions)>1 ? questionCourante.indice /
                                 fn:length(blocCourant.questions) : ''}" escapeXml="false" />
```

Comment: shouldn't it be like this ? - `     <c:out value="${blocCourant.titre} ${fn:length(blocCourant.questions)>1 ? questionCourante.indice + '/' +
                                 fn:length(blocCourant.questions) : ''}" escapeXml="false" />     `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break up your logic

Try this

```
  <c:if test="${fn:length(blocCourant.questions)>1}">
     <c:out value="${blocCourant.titre}  questionCourante.indice / ${fn:length(blocCourant.questions)}" escapeXml="false" />
    </c:if>
```

Comment: it should be ${questionCourante.indice} and not questionCourante.indice